# Disable Expect: 100 Continue in Play

Tags: http-headers, playframework-2.3, circleci

I'm working on an app in the Play Framework. Our tests for our scrapers make http requests to the sites from which they're scraping, which works fine on local machines, but when CircleCI tries to run our tests we get

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=417,
URL=http://www.ithaca.com/calendar/search/?advancedFormState=on&unrolled=1&q=&areaSelect=&d=&c%5B0%5D=calendar%2Fmusic%2A&venue_zip=&d1=6%2F9%2F2015&d2=&fl=&s=start_time&sd=asc&l=100&o=0
```

From what I can tell, this is likely due to CircleCI using a proxy to make HTTP requests, which can cause 417 errors when the Expect: 100 Continue header is included. Since we're not manually adding that header, I assume Play/Java is adding it. Is there any way to disable this and/or is there some other solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if Play really adds the header. Have you read https://jazzy.id.au/2013/07/16/100_continue_support_in_play.html?

Comment: @akkie I actually hadn't seen that, but that looks like dealing with the Play server responding to a client using the Expect: 100 Continue header, where in this instance Play is actually acting as a client, sending its own request to another server.